# How to append to a 2D list using a user input

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, input

How would I append to a 2D list using a user input if my list was

```
superheroes = [["Superman", "flying"], 
               ["Spiderman", "web"], 
               ["Batman", "Technology"], 
               ["Wonder woman","Lasso of Truth"]]
```

Answer (score 2):

Like you append to any list:

```
superheroes += [["Green lantern","A green lantern..."]]
```

or

```
superheroes.append(["Green lantern","A green lantern..."])
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following

```
temp = []
name = input("Enter Superhero's name")
temp.append(name)
type = input("Enter Superhero's type")
temp.append(type)
superheroes.append(temp)
```

This would ask the user for inputs for both the name and type of the superhero and add a list of those in your existing list.

Another way of king the user input and updating your list, in one line:

```
superheroes.append([input("Enter superhero's name"),input("Enter superhero's type")])
```